# When Selection A Date In Calendar It Goes Back To Rendered Date ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, calendar, render

I have a TextBox which represents a year.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="year" runat="server" Text="Year" MaxLength="4" Width="25%" OnTextChanged="updateYear" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

And a Calendar.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="cal" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>

                            <asp:Calendar ID="birthday" runat="server" OnDayRender="DayRender" style="margin-top:4px;" ForeColor="White" BackColor="Black" daynameformat="Shortest" Width="220px">
                                <TitleStyle BackColor="Black">
                                </TitleStyle>
                            </asp:Calendar>

            </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And here is the code for day render, which basically does not allow to enter an age that is less that 18:

```
public void DayRender(Object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (!calChenge)
    {
        if (e.Day.Date.Year > DateTime.Today.Year - 18)
        {
            e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.Day.Date.Year == DateTime.Today.Year - 18 && e.Day.Date.Month > DateTime.Today.Month)
            {
                e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
                e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            }
            else
            {
                if (e.Day.Date.Year == DateTime.Today.Year - 18 && e.Day.Date.Month == DateTime.Today.Month && e.Day.Date.Day > DateTime.Today.Day)
                {
                    e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
                    e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When the user enters a year into the TextBox and the year TextBox losses focus the Calendar goes to that year. For example the Calendar shows 10.04.1997, and the user writes in the year TextBox 1990 and losses focus, the Calendar updates to 10.04.1990 and automatically selects this date.

Here is the code for that:

```
protected void updateYear(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iYear = Convert.ToInt32(year.Text);
    if (iYear > 1890 && iYear < DateTime.Today.Year - 18)
    {
        int month = birthday.TodaysDate.Month;
        int day = birthday.TodaysDate.Day;
        DateTime today = new DateTime(iYear, month, day);
        birthday.TodaysDate = today;
        birthday.SelectedDate = today;
    }
}
```

After that when the user tries to select a different day, the Calendar does **not** select the date and goes to the date it was **rendered** (10.04.1997). I debugged it and found out that the day render executes just after the updateYear method, which probably interferes with the updateYear method.

In addition code in Page_Load:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
int year = date.Year - 18;
int month = date.Month;
int day = date.Day;
DateTime today = new DateTime(year, month, day);

birthday.TodaysDate = today;
birthday.SelectedDate = today;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Put an asynchronous trigger on the year textbox in your updatepanel.

Comment: put the code in your page_load in a if (!IsPostback) {...} condition.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="year"/>

 </Triggers>
```

inside the update panel

Comment: In the Page_Load added the code in the main question in the end

Answer (score 0):

The date always will be today's date with a different year, you only change the year, but the month and the day are `birthday.TodaysDate.Month` and `birthday.TodaysDate.Day` respectively.

Just change this

```
int month = birthday.TodaysDate.Month;
int day = birthday.TodaysDate.Day;
```

with this

```
int month = birthday.SelectedDate.Month;
int day = birthday.SelectedDate.Day;
```